# "Ending Session" toast message appears when turning off WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, toast-notifications

Recently, a message has been popping up when I turn off my WiFi, in and oval box saying "ending session", which never used to happen.

[image]

I would just ignore this if it wasn't for my phone seeming to slow down on downloads or using my browser and web pages take ages to load.

Is there a link here or is the message's appearance part of an update or something, or both?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of this message? It isn't normal. Also, please let us know what phone you have. Have you installed any new apps around the time the message started appearing?

Comment: Are you logged into any online apps like Skype or such that could bring up the message? Is there any notification in the notification area? Have you installed anything lately?

Comment: It's Netflix, I had the same problem and installed an app that identifies which apps make toasts. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mars3142.android.toaster